# Getting Firebase UserID from the script file in another file

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Inside of my script file I have the following code.

```
var getUserName = {
  username: null
};
```

When there is a change in user Auth, I do this.

```
getUserName.username = user.uid;
```

or if they logout.

```
getUserName.username = null;
```

This script file is located in a different folder than my main index file. However, in my main index file I am doing this...

```
 <script src="https://www.../level/script.js"></script>

 <script>
   setTimeout(alertFunc, 2000);

   function alertFunc() {
   console.log("Username from Script: " + getUserName.username);
 }
 </script>
```

But it tells me:

> getUserName is not defined at alertFunc

im scratching my head why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I over looked this a bit.

So for those who are not as dumb as me you will figure this out... but those who find this. Make sure that you put var `getUserName = {username: null};`as a global varable and not inside and `$(document).ready(function(){})` function.